# How to retrieve a Tags from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to retrieve a tags from database in my view and show it in post . but I have no idea of how I can done this ..

Here is my controller :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Book model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                            if(model.TagsListing != null)
            {
                Collection<Tag> postTags = new Collection<Tag>();
                var s = model.TagsListing.ToString();
                string[] newTags = s.Split(',');

                foreach (var val in newTags)
                {
                    Tag iTag = new Tag
                    {
                        Name = val
                    };
                    db.Tags.Add(iTag);
                    postTags.Add(iTag);
                }

                model.Tags = postTags;
            }


            db.Books.Add(model);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

            ViewBag.User_ID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email");
            ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Category_id", "Category_name");


        return View(model);

    }
```

and here is few pictures for my database :

[BookTag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjBgB.png)

[Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JzYO.png)

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hegxd.png
```

I just want to retrieve the tags related to the post and show them in post view .

Comment: in which action method are you trying to do it. What problem are you having ?

Comment: I have no problem , with method .. Just I attached the create controller to let you know how I saved the tags in my database , now I just want to retrieve them from database and show the tags related to a post in the post view page @Shyju

Comment: You need a GET action which queries your table and pass the data to a view where you will show it.

Comment: Which table I should make a query on it ?? cause already I have a taghandler who save a string of tags in book table , and also I have a booktagmap table who link between the book and tag but can't access it .. ??

Comment: What do you mean by **but can't access it** ? Did you try some code to read from the table(s) and got a "Permission denied/Unauthorized" error ?

Comment: if I make a method and a query on books table then it will return view of tagsHandler type , how to show this view in my book view ?? (I want to show the tags like stackoverflow under the question) .@Shyju

Comment: I mean the BookTag table can't be accessed since it's generated from many to many relation ..

Comment: Did you try `yourBookObj.Tags` ? Show us what you have triied

Comment: if I will use the Object.Tags , I can't return the tags related to the book because how I can know the tag id related to the book I have ????

Comment: Sorry ! I don't quite follow. You need to show us the code you tried, the expected behavior and what is not working.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Kpli32u.png   @Shyju

Comment: just I need to know how to show the tags in view ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a View model to show the Book details and the list of tags

```
public class BookDetailVm
{
  public int BookId { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<TagVm> Tags { set;get;}
  public BookDetailVm()
  {
    this.Tags = new List<TagVm>();
  }
}
public class TagVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}  
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action, read the Book entity and it's Tags collection property, map it to an instance of BookDetailVm and pass that to your view.

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var bookVm = new BookDetailVm();
    using (var db = new YourDbContext())
    {
        var book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);
        if (book != null)
        {
            bookVm.BookId = book.Id;
            bookVm.Name = book.Name;
            if (book.Tags != null)
            {
                bookVm.Tags = book.Tags
                                  .Select(b => new TagVm {Id = b.Id, Name = b.Name})
                                  .ToList();
            }            
        }            
   }
   return View(bookVm);
}
```

And your view which is strongly typed to our `BookdDetailVm`

```
@model BookDetailVm
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
<h3>Tags</h3>
@foreach(var t in Model.Tags)
{
  <p>@t.Id</p>
  <p>@t.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: just have a look here , this is method of int type return the number of page for pdf file , I just failed to call it from view, if you can help with that also and thanks http://i.imgur.com/rHhqPEM.png